# Read xml file with pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I want to read an xml file to pandas. Here is sample XML file

```
<author lang="en" class="1">
    <documents>
        <document><![CDATA[Hellow how are you]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[I am good]]></document>
        <document><![CDATA[What about you]]></document>
    </documents>
</author>
```

This is what I have tried

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('text.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('document')
```

But I don't know how to move ahead and get values from `itemlist`.
When I print it, I for following output

```
[<DOM Element: document at 0x170c9b229d0>,
 <DOM Element: document at 0x170c9b22a60>,
 <DOM Element: document at 0x170c9b22af0>]
```

How can I get strings out of it?

Comment: Perhaps give [read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) a try.

Comment: i know this, but its not in stable pip version and I am afraid updating to dev version may mess up things

Comment: just a variable in which output of `xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('document')` is stored

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need

```
import pandas as pd
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('text.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('document')

df = pd.DataFrame({"document": (i.firstChild.nodeValue for i in itemlist)})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
             document
0  Hellow how are you
1           I am good
2      What about you
```